# Is it possible to send a SMS contain one-time-token to specific phone number through Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to send an SMS containing a one-time-token to a specific phone number through Firebase Authentication?

Conditions:

1. My App is a multi-user web app.
2. There are 2 user roles in My App: Admin, and Member.

I want to:

1. Member user clicks a button.
2. Send an SMS containing a one-time token to the admin phone number.
3. Admin user tell a one-time-token member user.
4. Member user fills out a form and presses submit.
5. Token is sent back to the Firebase and verified.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is not a built-in flow for Firebase Authentication. The closest equivalent is Firebase's [phone number authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth), but in that scenario the one-time password (OTP) is sent to the user who signs in to the app.

So you can either modify your flow to use another step for involving the admin user, or you can [build your own provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) for Firebase Authentication. In the latter case, you won't be able to use Firebase to send the SMS messages though, but will have to use another provider for that.